# Jcouds hardware Id not found

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jclouds

Why can't I have some `r3.xlarge`  instances :(

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: hardwareId(r3.xlarge) not found
    at org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.throwNoSuchElementExceptionAfterLoggingHardwareIds(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:771)
    at org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.findHardwareWithId(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:758)
    at org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.build(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:695)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a known issue and it is already reporded in the jclouds JIRA. See [JCLOUDS-608](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-608). Once that issue is fixed you'll be able to use the R3 hardware profiles.